# What is the recommended extension for HLS chunks / segments? Are there recognised alternatives?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg to create HLS chunks AKA segments. I'm trying to find recognised extensions for HLS chunks.

All the documentation I've seen only ever uses a .ts extension when using ffmpeg ... something like this:

```
-hls_segment_filename "${outPath}/v%v/chunk%d.ts"
```

Is there an alternative recognised extension, since I'm working within a TypeScript project and TypeScript files also use a .ts extension and this is causing a conflict with various tools.

I don't want to use a non-standard extension for HLS chunks if I can help it. Are there any other known extensions for HLS chunks? TIA

Any pointers to documentation would be most welcome.

Comment: There's two extensions for HLS media segments: `.ts` or `.m4s`

Comment: Does this project offers any hints: https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js

Comment: @Gyan thanks but its seems that .m4s is for MPEG-DASH (which I didn't know so thanks) but .ts seems to be the only HLS recognised extension :( The project you gave points to .ts again

Comment: HLS supports both .ts and .m4s

Comment: @Gyan based on your help and my research I added an answer, please feel free to comment. Also, if you want to answer I will happily accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gyan said in the comments there are 2 extensions available for HLS namely `.ts` or `.m4s`

This is confirmed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#3314597) by Apple

Apple explain that `.ts` files are MPEG transport stream video files and `.m4s` files are Fragmented MP4 video or audio files.

You can't just change the extension willy nilly though. You need to generate the files using certain ffmpeg flags.

To generate `.ts` files use this flag (along with your other ffmpeg hls options):

```
-hls_segment_filename "${outPath}/v%v/chunk%d.ts"
```

To generate `.m4s` files use these flags:

```
-hls_segment_type fmp4
-hls_segment_filename "${outPath}/v%v/chunk%d.m4s"
```

Nice post on Fragmented Video [here](https://hlsbook.net/hls-fragmented-mp4/)

In performance testing I found .m4s to perform worse than .ts (in terms of seek speeds)

Comment: If you just use `-hls_segment_type` then FFmpeg will set segment file extension automatically, but if you use `-hls_segment_filename` then you have to pass a filename with the correct extension, in synchro with `-hls_segment_type` (even if default).